# Any alternative to ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED? I need an Intent/Action(/workaround) as soon as possible once the phone is powered on

Tags: android, android-intent

Lets say I have a WelcomeActivity. All it does is show you a welcome screen once the phone is switched on. I have successfully achieved this by extending a BroadcastListener for ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.

Problem : It takes a while for the phone to completely boot i.e send a BOOT_COMPLETED intent. SO before I can see my Welcome activity, I can see the whole process of the default home screen of my phone getting displayed, the network, wifi and gps detection and config taking place, message notification/status bar showing me new messages in inbox etc etc.

I dont want to wait this long. I am NOT saying that I want to suppress this genuine android system behavior. All I am saying is, show MyActivity as soon as the phone starts and let the phone boot in the background the way it does.

YES, I know the OS needs to kick start and reach a stable state for the DVM to start and thus in turn start my app. My question is is there any other genuine SDK(non-rooted) way of starting my activity a little early(as soon as possible) and not wait till BOOT_COMPLETED to be triggered?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say most likely not (Custom roms excluded)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hacking work around, but I actually have been working with BOOT_COMPLETED and another reciever WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION and noticed that the wifimanager was firing well before the boot completed.  Obviously if they have wifi and 3g off than that is pretty useless.

I think your best bet is to set a broadcast receiver for android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE.  I haven't tried it, but I would guess that it is one of the earlier ones fired.  Just make sure to add a boolean keeping track if this is really the boot or just a change in phone state.